# Add hostname that browser resolves?

Tags: dns, opera, hostname

My `/etc/hosts` has an entry similar to:

```
10.0.1.5     wiki
```

However, whenever I type `wiki` in Opera, the browser goes searching for the term "wiki".

If I include the trailing dot to make it a fully qualified domain name (i.e., enter `wiki.`), the behavior continues.

How do I add a hostname that the browser will resolve?

Comment: What if you use an FQDN? Does opera search for that term, too?

Comment: @Jan - I added the dot to make it a FQDN, but the issue persists. Good thought though.

Answer (score 0):

FQDN name must work, but it must look like url for browser.
Try

```
10.0.1.5       wiki    wiki.lan
```

and put wiki.lan in address bar.

Or put Full url

```
http://wiki
```

It because ugly heuristic in modern browsers.